# Listening to GPIO ports asynchronously or event-oriented

Tags: python

Today all programs in python for Raspberry boil down to:

```
while (True):
```

But is there anything like listening to GPIO ports asynchronously? Because in the previous form I consider a lot of 'structural programming' and if something happens down there it may not be read during the While.

Use something like the AsyncIO library?

An example of a switch button

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setmode (GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup (17, GPIO.IN)

while True:
   if (GPIO.input (17)):
  // if he presses the button again he will still be in this process.
```

Is there something like the Delegate in C #?

Comment: I have taken the liberty to remove the part that was posted twice in your question and edit a few capitalization errors with Python keywords.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use callbacks by whatever name they have in your Python GPIO library.

My [pigpio](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html) library uses [callback](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html#callback).

The equivalent in RPi.GPIO is event detect.

For a pigpio callback usage example see http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#Python_monitor_py which prints the GPIO, new level, and microseconds since the last change whenever a GPIO changes state.